# I converted this forEach code to for loop and the code is not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

Clicking the red exit button removes the player from the forEach code, but not for loop.

You click the blue button, next you click the red exit button to remove the player.

How would I get the for loop code to work the same as the forEach code?

This code is working.

https://jsfiddle.net/n1t3kjdw/

```
  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
    const el = evt.target;
    const container = el.closest(".container");
    const wrapper = container.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    wrapper.forEach(function(wrapper) {
      if (wrapper.player) {
        return removePlayer(wrapper);
      }
    });
  }
```

What did I do wrong here? https://jsfiddle.net/rbwsL8hf/

Why is this code not working, what needs to be fixed?

```
  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
const el = evt.target;
const container = el.closest(".container");
const wrappers = container.querySelectorAll(".wrap"); {
  for (let i = 0; i < wrappers[i].length; i++) {
    if (wrappers[i].player) {
      return removePlayer(wrappers[i]);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Why is this a bad question?

Comment: `return` in a `forEach` doesn't do anything, but your `return` in the `for` loop exits out of your function and thus stops the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your changed code you have made the iteration condition check for `wrappers[i].length` instead of what I believe was intended `wrappers.length`. Otherwise, you are for each iteration checking if `i` is smaller than the i-th wrapper's length which may or may not be defined.

```js
  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
const el = evt.target;
const container = el.closest(".container");
const wrappers = container.querySelectorAll(".wrap"); {
  for (let i = 0; i < wrappers[i].length; i++) { // HERE
    if (wrappers[i].player) {
      return removePlayer(wrappers[i]);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @Salim answer, there is also an extra bracket in your code, try this:

```
function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
   const el = evt.target;
   const container = el.closest(".container");
   const wrappers = container.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
     for (let i = 0; i < wrappers.length; i++) {
       if (wrappers[i].player) {
         return removePlayer(wrappers[i]);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you test it before posting an answer? https://jsfiddle.net/5zghujpa/ You click the blue button, next you click the red exit button to remove the player. It's not working.

Comment: I don't know what your intentions are with your code, the example you provided as "working", is working exactly the same with the code I provided